# Chef failing to set attributes after upgrade to 13.6.4

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

**EDIT** :: I edited the comment below, but to summarize here, this is what I've done to attempt to force an upgrade:

- Rebootstrap: this includes a manual add of "--bootstrap-version 13.6.4" to the bootstrap args, removing the client and node, bootstrapping with no cookbooks
- On the node itself, I tried to "yum erase chef" as well as manually removing every single file and folder containing "chef".
- I have rebooted the node as well

There is no reason a simple client upgrade should be this difficult.

---

I upgraded to Chef Client 13.6.4 from 12.21.3 recently. I used the method from the "Upgrading chef-client" doc ::

```
curl -L https://chef.io/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

The upgrade seemed to go successfully and when I start the client manually, I see the right version and it completes:

```
[root@hostname ~]# chef-client
Starting Chef Client, version 13.6.4
```

However, my nodes stopped checking in. When I examine the logs, it seems the daemon is running the old version:

```
[2017-11-27T10:08:13-05:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2017-11-27T10:08:13-05:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.21.3 ***
[2017-11-27T10:08:13-05:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
[2017-11-27T10:08:13-05:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 16337
[2017-11-27T10:08:57-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2017-11-27T10:08:57-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2017-11-27T10:08:57-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache    /chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-11-27T10:08:57-05:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-11-27T10:08:57-05:00] ERROR: Cannot find a platform for node[hostname]
```

I have killed the process and have restarted the service thru systemd. I have no idea why the manual invocation runs the right version but the daemon fails on the old version.

Comment: Check if you have a copy of the `chef` gem installed to the system Ruby perhaps?

Comment: @coderanger - i see this : `[root@hostname gems]# ls -ltr | grep -i chef
drwxr-xr-x.  9 root root 4096 Nov 20 09:52 chef-13.6.4` ... is that what you're talking about? If so , then it's the right version and we're good on that

Comment: Without knowing what folder that is in, I can't tell you what that means. But probably yes if `/usr/bin/gem list` shows the chef gem, then `/usr/bin/gem uninstall chef`.

Comment: Just to check, I ran  a `find / -name chef-*` . It only returned files containing "13.6.4", nothing on "12.21.3". A search of `find / -name "12.21.3"` produced nothing. I have rebooted the host; could this information be cached on the Chef Server itself? I'm going to re-bootstrap next.

Comment: No, which version of chef-client is run is entirely up to the client. Somewhere you have an old copy and the systemd unit probably has a different `$PATH` than your shell and is finding it :)

Answer (score 0):

**SECOND EDIT** :: On top of the rebootstrapping and the other steps mentioned, I had to do a full stop/start of the service (not a restart, that was not sufficient for whatever reason). That finally fixed it. So do all of these things and you to can perform your 'simple' Chef-client upgrade!

**CORRECTION** :: This did not fix the problem. I have rebootstrapped, removed the node and client from the server. I attempted to remove the package via yum, and even went so far as to manually blow away every directory and file containing the case-insensitive substring "chef". I bootstrapped with no cookbooks and even manually specified "--bootstrap-version 13.6.4". However, the node is still using the old version.

Rebootstrapping every single node fixed the problem. I made a simple bash script I will put here in case anyone else may need it:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat hosts`; do


  run_list=$(knife node show $i | grep "Run List" | sed s'/Run List:    //')
  IP=$(knife node show $i | grep "IP" | sed 's/IP:          //')
  env=$(knife node show $i | grep "Environment" | sed 's/Environment: //')

  echo y | knife node delete $i
  echo y | knife client delete $i

  knife bootstrap $IP -N $i -x my-user -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa --sudo --use-sudo-password -r recipe[chef-client]

  knife node run_list add $i $run_list

  knife node environment set $i $env

done
```